# can click on Checkbox in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome - Selenium(C#)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on a Checkbox in Chrome , but unable to do that. 
on the contrary , I'm able to do the same on IE and Firefox. 
Seems very weird to me. didn't find any solution yet. I'll be happy to have some, please.

That's the input id:

```html
<input id="ctl00_ctl55_g_0704d850_6481_416a_a414_9b4c51c8672f_ctl00_chkTerms" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl55$g_0704d850_6481_416a_a414_9b4c51c8672f$ctl00$chkTerms">
```

and this is how I'm finding it on C#:

```html
  var wait2 = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            var myElement2 = wait2.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl55_g_0704d850_6481_416a_a414_9b4c51c8672f_ctl00_chkTerms")));
            myElement2.Click();
```

Thanks
Yaniv

Comment: can u replicate this in public URL?

Answer (score 0):

What you get in the exception

```
try
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl55_g_0704d850_6481_416a_a414_9b4c51c8672f_ctl00_chkTerms")).Click();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
```

Comment: @Mrunal unfortunately I cant send a public url. Leon Im getting an invisible element. Seems like Chrome cant find it for some reason

Comment: Not sure I get you. How it has something to Israel bank website?

Comment: looks familiar, try to type me code and see what you get in the exception

Comment: Thats the exception:    
element not visible

  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)

  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: element not visible says that you need to hover on it (if its inside menu or something)

Comment: Is it possible that I need to hover on it only in Chrome? It works well on IE

Comment: try to update selenium/chrome webDriver to the last one

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the issue.
I have ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 which seems to be the latest. and chrome version 47.